# In Visual Studio 2012, how can I set a default related work item for TFS commits?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm working on refactoring a single code file from a TFS repository. I'm doing this refactor in chunks, making regular small commits. Our TFS policy requires me to associate every commit with a work item.

This means that every few minutes, when I right-click the code file and click *Check In Pending Changes*, I'll also have to click *Add a Work Item by ID* underneath *Related Work Items*, type in a number, and hit enter. The work item thing starts to get pretty tedious after a dozen commits on the same file and same work item in the space of an hour.

[image]
<sup>Above: The work item dialog I'm referring to, right at the end.</sup>

Is there some way to have a work item already specified by default, so I can just start the Check In process and have it already there?

I'll be working with this one file and this one work item for the next few days with lots of committing. If setting this up takes a few minutes and is fiddly, that's fine. It will be worth the time.

Comment: agreed!!!! this would be a nice feature to have

Answer (score 1):

I've asked the TFS Product Team for this feature in the past (to remember the last work item I associated with a check-in).  But AFAIK this is not currently possible.